# To block private Instagram profile from Google Search?

Tags: google-search, privacy, security, instagram

Many social media application have setting by which you can prevent your profile in Google search.
However, Instagram does not have it. 
They also ignore the users' feedback by not offering customer service, only their CEO's Twitter accounts.

**How can you prevent Instagram's private profiles in Google Search?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only decision to make here was to delete my Instagram profile. 
You cannot prevent even your private instagram profile from Google Search because Facebook pings the profile to Google.
Similarly, I had to remove my Spotify account because I had once connected it to Facebook, but Facebook never let's you go if you have done even it once. 
Similarly, I did not want my spotify profile to be visible in Google.

Answer (score 1):

Putting your profile on private might help. I tried googling "Instagram (my IG username)" and "Instagram (my IG name)" and my account didn't come up. However, when I googled a public IG account like "Instagram justinbieber", the link to his IG account topped the search results.